# How to find / search where a node is in geometry nodes tree

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, compositing-nodes, shader-nodes

How to find / search where a node is in geometry nodes tree.

**I have a large node tree and would like to be able search / find specific nodes like set material nodes**, is there a search or key combination to search for a node in a node tree that will take you to a specified node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and type the name of the node you're looking for.